# Translate model attributes after find in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just wanna translate some model attributes by applying

```
__("some text goes here")
```

i don't wanna write the code in all controllers and actions use the model, I wanna make the changes in the model.

Comment: I think using `scope` is the answer of your problem

Comment: Scopes for before find, but i need it update the model values after find.any suggestion ?

Comment: then make a helper method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate way to do this is to define an [accessor method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your model.

```
public function getSomeFieldToBeTranslatedAttribute($value)
{
     return __($value);
}
```

It's usually a good idea to keep things organized around your model when it's specific to the field.

Comment: Works Perfect, Thanks